# Jython: Trying to make a non object oriented API

Tags: java, python, jython

I am currently trying to port a java API into python for educational purposes and since I am new to python I am having issues making this API non object oriented.

For clarification, this is to teach introductory programming skills(boolean logic, function calls, loops, etc.)to students with no prior experience programming which is why we are aiming to remove as much object notation as possible.

While we have this working in java with a complete API, my attempts to implement this in python using the same environment have been less than successful. When calling any methods from the java API I have only had success when using the "self." qualifier or other predefined qualifiers in front of the method call.

Is there any way to make this work without any of these qualifiers?

In other words: where I currently have to call something like self.moveBall(50), or foo.moveBall(50) to call the moveBall() method in the predefined java API, I would like to simply be able to call moveBall() without any qualifiers.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: You just need to do `from <api> import *`.

Comment: I wonder what your working solution in Java looks like, since Java (unlike Python) doesn't provide you with the option to define a 'free' function that is independent a class.  Please clarify.  The closest thing that Java permits is a `static` method of a class.  The Python analog would be to decorate your methods with either `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod`, depending on your needs.  Or, to take things a step further by defining global, 'free' functions.